# Node : Run Method Against Array of Objects Async

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, parallel-processing

I have an array of homogeneous objects.  I want to be able to run a a method of each of the objects in parallel.  If I were to do this synchronously, it would look like:

```
var objs = [{run:function(){}},{run:function(){}},{run:function(){}}];

for (obj in objs) {
    obj.run();
}
```

I have thought about using async library, but don't see anything in there at jumps out at me that would work.

Comment: If the functions aren't async, they'd still run synchronously as there's only one thread in Node JS apps.

Answer (score 1):

You can map your objects to functions first, and then call these functions in parallel using [async.parallel](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel)

```
var async = require('async')

var objs = [{run:function(){}},{run:function(){}},{run:function(){}}];
var func2call = objs.map(function(x){return x.run})
async.parallel(func2call);
```